# Fastest way of resizing (rescaling) a 1D vector by an arbitrary factor

Tags: c++, arm, signal-processing, cortex-m

I have the following code that does the resizing of a 1D vector with nearest neighbor interpolation in a similar fashion you'd also resize an image. Another term would be resampling, but there seems to be a lot of confusion around these terms (resampling is also a technique in statistics), so I prefer to be more descriptive.

Currently the code looks like this and I need to optimize it:

```
inline void resizeNearestNeighbor(const int16_t* current, uint32_t currentSize, int16_t* out, uint32_t newSize, uint32_t offset = 0u)
{
    if(currentSize == newSize)
    {
        return;
    }

    const float scaleFactor = static_cast<float>(currentSize) / static_cast<float>(newSize);
    for(uint32_t outIdx = 0; outIdx<newSize; ++outIdx)
    {
        const int currentIdx = static_cast<uint32_t>(outIdx * scaleFactor);
        out[outIdx] = current[(currentIdx + offset)%currentSize];
    }
}
```

This of course is not hugely efficient because the operation to take the integer part of a float by downcasting is expensive and I don't think it can take any benefit of vectorization in this case. The platform is Cortex M7, so if you're familiar with any vectorization techniques on this platform, it would be also very helpful.

The use case of this code is a sound effect that allows for smoothly changing the length of a delay line (hence the additional offset parameter, since it's a ring buffer). Being able to smoothly change the length of a delay line sounds like slowing down or speeding up playback in a tape recorder, only it's in a loop. Without this scaling, there are lots of clicking noises and artifacts. Currently the hardware struggles with all the DSP and this code on top of that and it can't rescale long delay lines in real time.

Comment: You want to create a pitch-down effect to a sound ? If yes, what you need is an interpolation algorithm, you'll have to create extra samples between the existing ones with the correct interpolation to keep a smooth curve.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There are lots of parallel delay lines like this one and they're short so the nearest neighbor interpolation sounds sufficiently good in this case. They run through a low pass filter anyway. Ofc a better interpolation could help keep the quality better without aliasing etc, but it's not necessary here. I just need to optimize this code as much as possible.

Comment: In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M Cortex-M7 there are no vectorized instructions (unless they fall in the DSP instruction set). The SIMD set for 'M' series is Helium and that is optional even in the latest M55 CPU.

Comment: Is currentSize integer-power-of-2? Maybe you can get more performance by doing it in 2 steps: resize to the closest power-of-2 of target size using bitwise AND with (size-1). Then resize the result to the target size. In first one modulo gets faster, in second one the loop is vectorizable easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Cortex-M series is quite limited (even floating point in M7 is optional), I would estimate a reasonable speed-up coming from using Bresenham's mid point line drawing algorithm.

This algorithm always advances either N or N+1 elements based on the sign of the error term. The modulus does not need full length division: it suffices to compute `currentIdx += N + (delta < 0); if (currentIdx >= currentSize) currentIdx -= currentSize;`

One can also make a "trial divisions" in form of `if (currentIdx + 64 * (N+1) < currentSize)` to ensure that the next 64 elements do not need modular reduction. M7 has a multiplication unit, but multiplying by shifting is still likely a faster micro-optimisation.

The [Bresenham's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) for line drawing is of form

```
plotLine(x0, y0, x1, y1)
   dx = x1 - x0
   dy = y1 - y0
   D = 2*dy - dx
   y = y0

   for x from x0 to x1
       plot(x,y)
       if D > 0
           y = y + 1
           D = D - 2*dx
       end if
       D = D + 2*dy
```

Your application does not have x0,x1,y0,y1, but instead it has directly `dy = input_size`, `dx = output_size`.

```
resample(dx, dy)
   N = dy/dx
   dy = dy % dx
   D = 2*dy - dx;
   y = offset;
   for x from 0 to dx-1
       out[x] = in[y]
       y += N
       if D > 0
          y = y + 1
          D = D - 2*dx
       end if
       D = D + 2*dy
       if (y >= currentSize)
           y -= currentSize
```

The crucial modification to advance `y` by `N>0` steps is to `dy = dy % dx` to get the error computation correct.

One can also use slightly less accurate fixed point DDA algorithm with

```
int scale = 65536 * newSize / currentSize;
int y = offset << 16;
for (int x = 0; x < newSize; x++) {
    out[x] = in[y >> 16];
    y += scale;
    if (y >= (currentSize << 16))
        y -= (currentSize << 16);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `currentIdx`, you'll note that it is incremented by `scaleFactor` every time `outIdx` is incremented by one. Hence, you can replace `outIdx * scaleFactor` with `currentIdx += scaleFactor`.

You'd initialize `currentIdx` to `offset`, so that's hoisted from the loop as well.

`%currentSize` is an expensive operation as well, and one that appears to exist only for the non-zero offset case. You might want to treat that differently, and split the loop in two loops (before/after wrap-around point).

Comment: That solution only works for integral multiples of `scaleFactor`.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen: Where did you get that idea? Of course, for a non-integral `scaleFactor` you need a non-integral accumulator.

Comment: Right, I was just reading that `currentIdx` is `uint32_t`. Anyway the strength reduction is not particularly helpful in the case the M7 does not have the optional floating point unit.